# How to confirm progress of AWS Step Function using Cloud watch

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

I want to know how to confirm progress info of AWS Step Function using Cloud Watch API.

I thought I could get confirm progress info by using GetMetricStatistics method, but it did not work.

Below is the GetMetricStatistics(Amazon Cloud Watch API for JavaScript) 
Reference.

[enter link description here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html)

Please tell me how to confirm progress info of AWS Step Function using Cloud Watch API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> To establish a baseline you should, at a minimum, monitor the following metrics:
>
> ActivitiesStarted
> ActivitiesTimedOut
> ExecutionsStarted
> ExecutionsTimedOut
> LambdaFunctionsStarted
> LambdaFunctionsTimedOut
> ```

And:

> ```
> State Machine Metrics
>
> The following metrics are available for Step Functions state machines:
>
> Execution Metrics
>
> The AWS/States namespace includes the following metrics for Step Functions executions:
>
> Metric    Description
> ExecutionTime The interval, in milliseconds, between the time the execution starts and the time it closes.
> ExecutionThrottled    The number of StateEntered events in addition to retries.
> ExecutionsAborted The number of aborted or terminated executions.
> ExecutionsFailed  The number of failed executions.
> ExecutionsStarted The number of started executions.
> ExecutionsSucceeded   The number of successfully completed executions.
> ExecutionsTimedOut    The number of executions that time out for any reason.
> ```

[Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-cw-metrics.html)